# Change default WordPress 'text indent' from <p> to <span>

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Can someone tell me if it possible to replace the text indent button from

```
<p style="padding-left: 40px;"></p>
```

to

```
<span style="padding-left: 40px;"></span>
```

I don't really want to be copying the span code every time I want to indent something so it would be good to override the default WordPress `<p>` for indenting with a `<span>`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is this in default editor?

Comment: I think `text-indent` is the property you need to use. More information from: [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-indent.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-indent.asp)